# Ionic + jQuery : transfer data between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I know that it's not the best title for this question, but if someone has a better one, you can edit my question.

I'm currently developing an app with Ionic v1, but, for the JS part, I use Angular and **jQuery 3.1.1**. My problem is that I have a list of items, and when I click on one item, I'll be redirected to the search page, with the item name on the search input. This is my JS code for the item list part:

```
localStorage.setItem("query", "");
  $(".item").click(function () {
    var query = $(this).text();
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      console.log(query);
      localStorage.setItem("query", query);
      window.location.href = '#tab/search';
    } else {
        // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
        console.log("No web storage");
    }
  });
```

and I retrieve the "query" row in the search controller:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      var query = localStorage.getItem("query");
      console.log(query);
      window.setInterval(function(){
        var query = localStorage.getItem("query");
        if (query != "") {
          $(".query").val(query);
        }
      }, 250);
        // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem("query", "");
    } else {
        // Sorry! No Web Storage support...
        console.log("No web storage");
    }
```

The thing is that it doesn't work the first time, but the second time, and the third time, it works. The most horrible thing is that I don't even know why it's doing that.